# Does using SecureNSUserDefaults as cryptography in the App Store?

Tags: ios, iphone, encryption, app-store, app-store-connect

I planned to use `SecureNSUserDefaults` to encrypt things in my app, i have messages app and i add the messages to favorite using encryption. its static messages app. so i am having a trouble of selection when i need to submit my app to the store.

`SecureNSUserDefaults` uses `CocoaSecurity` Library for AES 356-bit encryption. well its confusing to choose from the following choices when submission . its the first time I'm using encryption and I'm confused of what choices am i supposed to choose.

[image]

By me choosing to use the encryption in my app is for protecting from stealing the content so is it considered as : `(b) Limited to intellectual property and copyright protection` ?

**Update :** Ive Contacted the owner of the library and he said it was an error so its 256-bit. but i tried to encrypt the same like "HelloWorld" with library and online using website with 256-bit and with same key and i get so different results. and the library is producing very long keys which is confusing !

Comment: If you are using AES encryption then yes you have to admit it. But, don't use "SecureNSUserDefaults", it can't even get the AES key size correct, there are only three AES key sizes:128-bit, 192-bit and 256-bit, there is no AES 356-bit encryption. That alone should make you seriously wonder if the author is to be trusted.

Comment: @zaph maybe it was a typing error ?

Comment: I've updated the question !

Comment: @zaph , is it considered that I'm protecting my copyright, so for the third question. YES should be the answer right ?

Comment: Would you trust a developer who would make a mistake claiming AES-356 encryption? I would not.  There are several well known and libraries to choose from. But your security is up to your judgement.

Comment: A Copyright *is* protection.

Comment: Okey, Will you pass me some methods or library to encrypt ? something better that the one I'm using ? Btw I've looked at his library its actually not doing anything wrong ! its just passing the data to CocoaSecurity to Base64 and save it in NSUserDefaults. and same to decrypt your right about the mistake of 356-bit !  @zaph

Comment: its using the following method : key -> SHA384(key).sub(0, 32)
iv -> SHA384(key).sub(32, 16) .

Comment: [CocoaSecurity](https://github.com/kelp404/CocoaSecurity) it is not terrible but I would not use it, it uses SHA to derive the encryption key from from a password and that is not good, the current practice is to use a key derivation function such as  PBKDF2 which is much more secure. You will have to match the protocol on .NET and that is not detailed, you will have to read the code to figure it out. It has not been updated in a year or more.

Comment: One problem with `NSUserDefaults` is that it combines all uses into one plist file. This removes separation between classes and allows one class to influence the performance of another class. Another is the keys are strings which do not allow compiler support against typos.

Comment: key -> SHA384(key).sub(0, 32) iv -> SHA384(key).sub(32, 16) does not really make any sense. Is that two invocations of SHA384, DES does not use a 32-byte key, where does the key argument come from in the first SHA384(key)? Are you trying to create an HMAC, if so that is no longer a best practice, use PBKDF2  to extend a key.  Security is not easy to get right. I suggest you get a cryptographic domain expert to help or just go with whatever you feel good about. The latter seems to be the most popular case.

Comment: @zaph, Well i just really want to use the library to secure my content ! so if answered YES for the first three questions that wouldn't be a problem for me in the future to delete my app from the store ?